# Setting the singular side of a to-many relationship in Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, ios6

I've got a little function where I query objects through a relationship in my Core Data model.

I have the to-many side of the relationship all setup. However, I cannot figure out how to properly set the singular side of the relationship as it's considered an `NSSet`, and I have no idea what to do with that.

[image: data model]

I've tried putting objects within an `NSSet` that I would like to assign to the other "to-many" entity, but that returned an error.

I tried looking through the documentation, and the only examples I found were for a many-many relationship.

I tried searching on SO a little, and couldn't find anyone who had asked this specific question.

Hopefully somebody out there can understand what I'm asking for, and help me out!

**EDIT:**

To help you all visualize, I have set the "shindys" side of the relationship, but now I'm trying to set the "user" side, which, as you can see, is a singular relationship.

**EDIT:**

After @Mundi's answer below, I have this as my data model:

[image]

That all is correct, I just need to have the ability to fetch all of the user's friends shindy's along with their own. You could compare this to Twitter's home feed.

Comment: could you supply more information like the data structure? I'm not sure i understand your problam

Comment: Of course, I figured it would be too difficult to follow. See my edit.

Comment: May the below tutorial helps you http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates

Comment: There's nothing in there that I saw that explains a one-many relationship.

Comment: So now you are basically trying to add users?

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to keep track of what user creates what "shindy" so I can fetch it later and it be nice and sorted for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have your data model set up the wrong way.

One user can have many messages. One message has at least two users (from and to). I do not know what a shindy is, but the way you have set it up, one user has only one shindy which can be shared among several users.

If this is correct, you need to change the message part of your data model and either make it many-to-many, or better make two relationships that describe sender and receiver.

```
Message                       User
  sender <<-------------------->sentMessages
  receivers <<---------------->>receivedMessages
```

<strike>Also, you should rename your user attribute "shindys" to "shindy", as it is only singular.</strike> Now that we know that shindy is a party, you should change that relationship to a many-to-many.

So to sort your users by shindy if there is only one shindy per user (whatever that is, please elucidate us) you would use a sort descriptor like this

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"shindy.timePosted" ascending:NO];
```

If, however, you want to filter by shindy (all users belonging to a shindy if there are several) you would have to use a predicate, like this

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY shindies.profileID = %@", 
                                                someUser.profileID];
```

or use some other way to identify the shindy.

Comment: I'm loving your attempts at interpreting the word "shindy" lol. Shindy is the word that people used back in the 1800's to describe a party. The app I'm building is based on partying, so I thought the word would suit it perfectly :)

Anyways, I see what you're saying. I wasn't all too focused on the messages entity at the moment as I had just made it, but thank you a lot for that! As for the Shindy entity: you have a good point. I will re-write my code to reflect this, and hopefully your solution is the one I'm looking for!

Comment: The problem I have now is that I have a feed where one user can see all of the shindys that their friends are throwing. I need some way to fetch all of their friend's shindys along with their own as well. Think of a platform similar to Twitter. If you can inform me on how I could do that, I believe you have completely answered my question! So far, everything you've posted is right. I appreciate your help. See my edit.

Comment: You have not defined a relationship "friends".

Comment: I know. What I was insinuating was that I had planned to create one, but then how do I pull their shindys in combined with the current users? I can't really do two combined `NSFetchRequests`, so how would I do it?

Comment: You use fetch requests with predicates. It is quite simple really. The guests of a shindy would simply be `shindyObject.users`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that you could set predicates with dot notation. That's freaking cool :) Thanks for your help!